# How Can I exec a function when user press a key on React using Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, keyboard-events

**I need that my react component exec a function when user press a key** (keyUp), but i have the next error:

```
react-dom.development.js:55 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Too many re-renders. 
React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

I am using a hook to event's keyboard:

```
function useKey(key) {
  const [pressed, setPressed] = useState(false)
  const match = event => key.toLowerCase() == event.key.toLowerCase()
  const onDown = event => {
    if (match(event)) {  setPressed(true) }
  }
  const onUp = event => {
    if (match(event)) { setPressed(false) }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", onDown)
    window.addEventListener("keyup", onUp)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", onDown)
      window.removeEventListener("keyup", onUp)
    }
  }, [key])
  return pressed
}
```

and my component:

```
function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState("state")
  const key = useKey('ArrowUp')
  if(key){
    // TODO
    setState({...state})
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {state}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Code is here https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-ellis-zrgkt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your setState is causing issue. Move state update in useEffect hook, whenever there is change in key check if key is true then update your state.

```
function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState("state")
  const key = useKey('ArrowUp')
  useEffect(() => {
    if(key) setState({...state});
  }, [key])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {state}
    </div>
  );
}
```